# Boost Multi-Index remove elements using list of indexes

Tags: c++, boost, multi-index, boost-multi-index

My multiindex looks like this:

```
using pair = std::pair<int, int>;

struct Hasher{
    std::size_t operator()(const int& k) const{
        return std::hash<int>()(k);
    }
};

using memberFirst = member<
            pair,
            pair::first_type,
            &pair::first
            >;
using memberSecond = member<
            pair,
            pair::second_type,
            &pair::second
            >;

using Container = multi_index_container<
    pair,
    indexed_by<
        random_access<>,
        hashed_non_unique<memberFirst, Hasher>,
        hashed_non_unique<memberSecond, Hasher>
        >
    >;

Container container;
```

I have `std::vector<int> indexes{10, 32, 55, 66};`. This vector represent indexes, what I want to remove.

When I remove something I have to preserve insert order. For example:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 // remove {2,5,7}
1,3,4,6,8,9
```

To achieve this I can use:

```
int index = 0;
auto it = indexes.begin();
container.remove_if([&index, &it](auto& e){
    (void)e; //never use
    if(index++ == *it){
        ++it;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

But it is not optimal way to do it, because I know exactly where to start looking for element: `conteiner.begin()+indexes[0];` and I don't know how elements are removed:

- index was remove and other indexes were moved by one to the left
- index was remove and other indexes were move by number of items removed before to the left

So my gool is something like this(pseudo c++ code):

```
iterator remove_if(iterator begin, iterator end, lambda){
    int moveBy = 0;
    while(begin != end){
        if(lambda(begin.value)){
            ++moveBy;
        }else if(moveBy){
            (begin-moveBy).value = begin.value;
        }
        ++begin;
    }
    return end-moveBy;
}
```

And I could use it like this:

```
container.erase(remove_if(container.begin()+indexes[0], container.end(), [..](..){...}), container.end());
```

Or there is more clever way to do this.

**Question:** How can I implement it or how can I improve it!

Comment: Your "gool" looks like a [`std::[stable_]partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `relocate` to efficiently move target elements to the end of the index and then erase them all in one fell swoop:

**<kbd>[Live Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c8e400df8fd265a)</kbd>**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <cassert>

template<typename RandomAccessIndex,typename FwdIterator>
void remove_positions(RandomAccessIndex& i,FwdIterator first,FwdIterator last)
{
  assert(std::is_sorted(first,last));
  assert(last==std::adjacent_find(first,last));
  
  if(first==last)return;
  
  std::size_t n=*first++,s=1;
  for(;first!=last;++first,++s){
    std::size_t m=*first;
    i.relocate(i.begin()+m,i.begin()+n,i.begin()+n+s);
    n=m-s;
  }
  i.relocate(i.end(),i.begin()+n,i.begin()+n+s);
  i.erase(i.end()-s,i.end());
}

template<typename RandomAccessIndex,typename Seq>
void remove_positions(RandomAccessIndex& i,const Seq& seq)
{
  remove_positions(i,seq.begin(),seq.end());
}

template<typename RandomAccessIndex>
void remove_positions(RandomAccessIndex& i,std::initializer_list<std::size_t> seq)
{
  remove_positions(i,seq.begin(),seq.end());
}

// testing

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/key.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::multi_index;
using pair=std::pair<int,int>;
using container=multi_index_container<
  pair,
  indexed_by<
    random_access<>,
    hashed_non_unique<key<&pair::first>>,
    hashed_non_unique<key<&pair::second>>
  >
>;

int main()
{
  container c={
    {0,0},{1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4},
    {5,5},{6,6},{7,7},{8,8},{9,9}
  };
  
  remove_positions(c,{2,5,7});
  
  for(const pair& p:c)std::cout<<p.first<<" ";
}
```

**Output**

```
0 1 3 4 6 8 9
```

Comment: Relocate is a nice building block. I would probably never do it this way unless profiler told me it was significantly faster than using an algorithm to do the effective remove_if. It might be I guess.

Comment: Definitely profiling is the way to go. From a theoretical point of view, this is linear time, though

Comment: With sufficient optimization looks like this is just as well: https://godbolt.org/z/9frnaj38d

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. It's what I was looking for. In the end (after a lot of tests) this approach is still slower then using built-in method remove_if. It's a bit sad that this container doesn't have overloaded this function for specific starting point... If I could somehow use std::remove_if I could make the same result like I wanted to do, without iterating by every element in the container. Erase function is incredible slow for this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use standard library algorithms here.

It strikes me that you can use the `random_access` iterator with `std::stable_partition` to sort all the removables at the end before erasing in bulk:

```
using Record = std::pair<int, int>;

struct Hasher : std::hash<int> { };
using memberFirst  = bmi::member<Record, Record::first_type, &Record::first>;
using memberSecond = bmi::member<Record, Record::second_type, &Record::second>;

using Container = bmi::multi_index_container<
    Record,                                          //
    bmi::indexed_by<                                 //
        bmi::random_access<>,                        //
        bmi::hashed_non_unique<memberFirst, Hasher>, //
        bmi::hashed_non_unique<memberSecond, Hasher> //
        >>;
```

> *I renamed the value type to `Record` to avoid confusion  with `std::pair`*

```
void remove_indices(Container& from, std::vector<int> const& removables) {
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Record const>> //
        arrangement(from.begin(), from.end());

    auto pivot = std::stable_partition(
        arrangement.begin(), arrangement.end(), [&](Record const& rec) {
            auto index = from.iterator_to(rec) - from.begin();
            return (end(removables) ==
                    std::find(removables.begin(), removables.end(), index));
        });

    from.rearrange(begin(arrangement));
    auto n_remaining = pivot - arrangement.begin();
    from.erase(from.begin() + n_remaining, from.end());
}
```

Demo **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/zavbq36WT)**:

```
Before [(1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33), (4, 44), (5, 55), (6, 66), (7, 77), (8, 88), (9, 99)]
After [(1, 11), (2, 22), (4, 44), (5, 55), (7, 77), (9, 99)]
```

### Simpler And More Efficient?

It strikes me that the complexity largely vanishes if you know that:

- indexes are a fixed order
- not duplicated

So, let's use that idea as well:

```
void remove_indices(Container& from, std::set<int, std::greater<> > const& descending) {
    for (auto& index : descending)
        from.erase(from.iterator_to(from[index]));
}
```

This trades efficiencies and complexities. Use taste and profilers to decide which version to use. See it live again:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/n68zah397)**

```
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

using Record = std::pair<int, int>;

struct Hasher : std::hash<int> { };
using memberFirst  = bmi::member<Record, Record::first_type, &Record::first>;
using memberSecond = bmi::member<Record, Record::second_type, &Record::second>;

using Container = bmi::multi_index_container<
    Record,                                          //
    bmi::indexed_by<                                 //
        bmi::random_access<>,                        //
        bmi::hashed_non_unique<memberFirst, Hasher>, //
        bmi::hashed_non_unique<memberSecond, Hasher> //
        >>;

void remove_indices(Container& from, std::set<int, std::greater<> > const& descending) {
    for (auto& index : descending)
        from.erase(from.iterator_to(from[index]));
}

#include <fmt/ranges.h>
int main() {
    Container container{
        {1, 11}, {2, 22}, {3, 33},   {4, 44},   {5, 55},   {6, 66},   {7, 77},
        {8, 88}, {9, 99},
    };

    fmt::print("Before {}\n", container);

    remove_indices(container, {2,5,7});
    fmt::print("After {}\n", container);
}
```

Prints

```
Before {(1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33), (4, 44), (5, 55), (6, 66), (7, 77), (8, 88), (9, 99)}
After {(1, 11), (2, 22), (4, 44), (5, 55), (7, 77), (9, 99)}
```

### Side Note

One of the main advantages of MultiIndex containers is that you don't have to settle for non-descript types like `std::pair` with nondescript names as `first` or `second_type`. Brrr. Much nicer:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ccGa7K7E7)**

```
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>

#include <fmt/ostream.h>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <iomanip>

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

struct Record {
    int age;
    std::string name;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Record const& r) {
        return os << "(" << std::quoted(r.name) << "," << r.age << ")";
    }
};

using Container = bmi::multi_index_container<
    Record,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::random_access<>,
        bmi::hashed_non_unique<bmi::member<Record, std::string, &Record::name>>,
        bmi::hashed_non_unique<bmi::member<Record, int, &Record::age>>
        >>;

void remove_indices(Container&                           from,
                    std::set<int, std::greater<>> const& descending)
{
    for (auto& index : descending)
        from.erase(from.iterator_to(from[index]));
}

int main() {
    Container container{
        {1, "Alyssa"}, {2, "Baya"},   {3, "Chom"},  {4, "Dirk"},  {5, "Evie"},
        {6, "Ferd"},   {7, "Gerald"}, {8, "Homer"}, {9, "Isala"},
    };

    fmt::print("Before {}\n", container);

    remove_indices(container, {7, 2, 5, 7});
    fmt::print("After {}\n", container);
}
```

Prints

```
Before {("Alyssa",1), ("Baya",2), ("Chom",3), ("Dirk",4), ("Evie",5), ("Ferd",6), ("Gerald",7), ("Homer",8), ("Isala",9)}
After {("Alyssa",1), ("Baya",2), ("Dirk",4), ("Evie",5), ("Gerald",7), ("Isala",9)}
```

Comment: (first code)And still the iterator move one by one element in`container`. I don't realy care about elements that's I just remove, becouse I will not use it. Only the remaining matter.`std::vector<int>indexes` are sorded and unique, so first index should be the staring point in container. Why should I use 3 loops for: rearrange`arrangmend`, rearange`container` and erase elements. If in the`container{1,2,3,4,5,6}` I remove`{1,2}` and after that container lookes like this`{3,4,5,6,5,6}` it's still fine because I don't need last 2 indexes I want to remove them`{3,4,5,6}`. Question is can i do it.

Comment: I started thinking about using `modify`, by looping from: `container.begin()+indexes[0]` to `container.end() or indexes.end()`

Comment: Modify can only ever modify a single element.

Comment: Note that "If in thecontainer{1,2,3,4,5,6} I remove{1,2}" should result in  {1,3,4,5,6}` since `{1,2}` are indices and not values?

Comment: You didn't respond to the second approach. And to "why should I [...]]" - You don't have to do anything. You asked "Or there is more clever way to do this." and I'm trying to help.

Comment: `{1,2,3,4 ...}` are items position before remove in container(indexes), so after removed some, they order is still the same `{2,3,5,7,9,10 ...}` container[0] == [2](starting index) and if I remove it again it can looks like this `{10,45,70 ...}`. container[0] == [10](starting index)

Comment: I sorry, but there is characters limit.. If I understand correctly second approach do something like this:
`container{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}`,`remove{1,2,3}`
1. find position of index;
2. get iterator to it;
3. erase it;
4. move evrythink to left {2,3,4,5,6,7};
5. back to point 1 if index !=remove.end()

Comment: The second approach is exactly in the answer, with a live demo. There's nothing "something like this" about it?

Comment: All multi-index containers are nodebased, so "move evrythink to left" never happens. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59163757/85371. It doesn't matter in which order elements are erased, in terms of performance. The reason to care about the ordering is *ONLY* because the indexes would change meaning

Comment: Isn't it to slow? we have to `!n` times repeat moving elements, when we can do it `n` times.

Comment: I suggest you read the links I gave you, or just measure. Again, there is **no** "moving elements" due to node-based storage.

Comment: Here's a take that doesn't use `std::set` instead `assert`-ing that the indices to remove are specified in ascending order and strictly unique: https://godbolt.org/z/o5KvYqTE3

Comment: Oof I copy-paste errored badly there. It should obviously have been a vector there: https://godbolt.org/z/aKv1rxfqv